# Multiexperiments in iddata function from Matlab's system ID toolbox

Tags: matlab, version, system-identification

I am trying to evaluate with `iddata` ([**INFO**](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/ident/ug/dealing-with-multi-experiment-data-and-merging-models.html)) in matlab, a number of `N_E` experiments.
I already computed and have as cell arrays of size 1x`N_E` the outputs and inputs, `y` and `u` respectively. Every entry of the cell arrays `y` and `u` is a vector of length `N=316` (SISO system). For the sake of correctness, `period` is also a cell array of size 1x`N_E`, with the period in every entry.

Using the command:

```
data = iddata(y,u,period);
```

doesn't produce the expected *averaged* data-set. Instead, it is handled as a `361`x`361`MIMO system (!).

I've already tried transposing, without results.

```
data = iddata(y.',u.',period.');
```

**Does someone know why this happens, and how can I produce the desired multi-experiment data-set?**

P.S. the documentation I read is for Matlab R2014b, and I am running R2013b. Does someone know if this was not supported in my edition? Or how can I find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the Matlab documentation provides an answer to my question.
The function `iddata` is very strict regarding how the dimension of output `y`, input `u` and period `period` are defined.

Defining `1xN_experiments` cell arrays for `y`,`u` and `period` (note: **same size for all**!; also `N_experimentsx1` won't be recognized by `iddata`) and then using `iddata`:

```
data = iddata(y,u,period);
```

gives the desired `iddata` structure.

**Note** all vectors within `y` and `u` must be of same length(!)